# How can one download a video from a news site?

Tags: video, download, html, source-code, json

How would one go about downloading the main video shown on this webpage? It seems very tricky getting into the source code.

https://www.news.com.au/technology/innovation/military/putins-super-weapons-moscow-gives-us-a-new-look-at-its-future-arsenal/news-story/b97a0720bac92428941da476e898fd3b

```
<div preload="none" data-embed="default" data-player="Bym4SOu4Rx" data-video-id="5743531955001" data-account="5348771529001" class="video-js vjs-controls-enabled vjs-workinghover vjs-v6 bc-player-Bym4SOu4Rx_default bc-player-Bym4SOu4Rx_default-index-0 vjs-mouse vjs-dock vjs-plugins-ready vjs-errors vjs-vpaid-controls-disabled vjs-ima3-html5 ima3-loading-spinner vjs-ad-controls vjs-has-started integral-vid-dd57f14314041942f137ab525d08e0b4 vjs-paused not-hover vjs-user-active" id="p-5348771529001-5743531955001" role="region" aria-label="Video Player" style="width: 650px;" data-integralas-id-7985b670-b8e8-e178-8ee2-6bac817fdde8="" lang="en-gb">

<video id="p-5348771529001-5743531955001_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" data-account="5348771529001" data-video-id="5743531955001" data-player="Bym4SOu4Rx" data-embed="default" preload="metadata" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="vjs-dock-title-1" aria-describedby="vjs-dock-description-2" src="blob:https://www.news.com.au/32e95726-351b-45a2-9fa6-c98441ba4be2" autoplay="autoplay" style=""></video>

<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/vttjs/0.12.5/vtt.global.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing this from firefox's dev tools so your mileage may vary depending on your browser. Try having a look at the network tab and filter the request type to media. When playing the video you should see `GET` requests going to a Content delivery network. From the looks of it the video is split into multiple parts. The name of the requests should correspond to the id in the video tag. You can then right click and copy each url and paste them into your browser which should download the segment. Or you can use `wget` or similar programs to do the downloading.

[image]

You'll probably need to use some file joiner to reform it into a single file. Don't do much video editing so not sure if a standard file join will work or mess something up with the encoding so you'll have to play around with it.